# Login is not working in selenium webdriver 3.4.0 version

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Login is not working in selenium webdriver 3.4.0 version.

Source Code :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Jars\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    InternetExplorerDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
    // Navigating to URL
            driver.navigate().to("https://login.yahoo.com/");

            //finding Username field
            driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("randomusername");

            // Clicking on Next button
            driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();

            //Thread.sleep(3000);

            // Entering the password field
            driver.findElement(By.id("login-passwd")).sendKeys("random_password");

            // Clicking on Signin button
            driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();

            // Driver Closing
            driver.close();

}
```

Please suggest me any solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific.. I think you wrote a correct code in the question itself.

Comment: @laxman Did you get any error? Post the error too.

Comment: Where are you facing the error? Can you print the error stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because your password field is becoming stale after you have entered Your Login ID; so in order to avoid working with stale element you have to check for that element to be present again in DOM; hence using some explicit wait as below:

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(driver.findElement(By.id("login-passwd"))));

  driver.findElement(By.id("login-passwd")).sendKeys("random_password");
```